# use devise sign_in view in layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have 2 layout

1. applicattion.html.erb
2. login.html.erb

I use devise.
in application_controller.rb I write this code:

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout :another_by_method
  private
  def another_by_method
    if user_signed_in?
      "application"
    else
      "login"
    end
  end
```

by this code, if user don't login_in, login.html.erb show.
I want use devise sign_in form in login.html.erb, but because of this code all of the page are redirect_to login.html.
I use below code too,

```
<%= render partial: "devise/sessions/new"%>
```

but get this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Devise::Sessions#new
```

any idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to render a partial, but `devise/sessions/new` is not a partial.

Anyway, have you generated the views with `rails generate devise:views`? If so, you could do that:

```
= render file: 'devise/sessions/new'
```

Use `file` instead of `partial`, but you will need all the variables provided by Devise, as resource, resource_name, or devise_mapping.

Comment: Thats ok for sign in, but when I sign out, I get [NameError in Home#index].
Home is the root page and if user signed_in, the page is redirect to dashboard.
whats the problem?!

Comment: Ok, I think you need to add a new question about sign out error, because this one was about sign in.